# How to save the result in the previous matrix instead of making a new one

Tags: python

In this code when the term_frequency matrix is normalized, I made a new matrix called tf_normalize but my train data is extremely big and it makes memory-error so could anyone help me how I can save the normalized vectors (tf_normalize) in the first matrix I made, i.e term_frequency:

```
      import nltk
      from nltk import stem
      from nltk.corpus import stopwords
      stop = stopwords.words('english')
      stemmer=stem.PorterStemmer()

      word_list={}
      import math
      with open('train_data.txt','r') as traindata:
      for line in traindata:
        words=line.split()
        for w in words:
            w = stemmer.stem(w)
            if w not in stop:
                try:
                    word_list[w]+=1

                except:
                    word_list[w]=1


   ##        print(word_list)
    print(len(word_list.keys()))
          List_of_word_list=list(word_list.keys())

   ##    print(List_of_word_list)

    #creates the tf matrix
    term_frequency=[]
    with open('train_data.txt','r') as traindata:
        for line in traindata:
             words=line.split()
             vocabulary=[]
             for w in List_of_word_list:
                vocabulary.append(words.count(w))
             term_frequency.append(vocabulary)
    ##    print(term_frequency)
    print(len(term_frequency))

   ## calculates the magnitude of each vector in term_frequency matrix
   def magnitude(v):
    for vector in term_frequency:
        return math.sqrt(sum(v[i]*v[i] for i in range(len(v))))

   ## normalizes the vectors of the term_frequency matrix
   def normalize(v):
     vmag=magnitude(v)
     for vector in term_frequency:
        return [ v[i]/vmag for i in range(len(vector))]

   tf_normalize = []
   for vector in term_frequency:

        tf_normalize.append(normalize(vector))

    print(tf_normalize)

   for t in tf_normalize:
      print(magnitude(t))
```

Answer (score 0):

Late edit: it's confusing that you refer to the corpus as traindata and the desktop file data.txt as traindata. I presume the latter is termdata.

Where you build term_frequency as a list and add things to it:

```
   ...
   for line in traindata:
     words=line.split()
     vocabulary=[]
     for w in List_of_word_list:
        vocabulary.append(words.count(w))
     term_frequency.append(vocabulary)
   ...
```

so you have one entry in term_frequency for each line of your term data (called traindata), and that entry is a list as long as your list_of_word_list. Is that what you mean to do? Maybe that is what you mean to do but you're not exactly making your data more condensed. I'm guessing you want to get a total count of the words in your termdata which are in your corpus. Wouldn't it be a lot more efficient if term_frequency instead is a dictionary containing ONLY count of words found in termdata which are in the corpus, so words not in your term data don't appear in term_frequency because they have a count of zero? Also, should you be stemming the words in your termdata?

Something like:

```
   term_frequency = {}
   for line in termdata:
     words=line.split()
     for w in words:
       # assuming that words from termdata should be stemmed
       stemmedword = stemmer.stem(w)
       if stemmedword in List_of_word_list:
         try:
           term_frequency[stemmedword ] += 1
         except:
           term_frequency[stemmedword ] = 1
```

Or, if you really do want an entry in term_frequency for each line of termdata, keep term_frequency as a list but make each entry a dictionary of the words in the line which are also in List_of_word_list:

```
   term_frequency = []
   for line in termdata:
     line_frequency = {}
     words=line.split()
     for w in words:
       # assuming that words from termdata should be stemmed
       stemmedword = stemmer.stem(w)
       if stemmedword in List_of_word_list:
         try:
           line_frequency[stemmedword ] += 1
         except:
           line_frequency[stemmedword ] = 1
     term_frequency.append(line_frequency)
```

Using dictionaries for the normalize might look something like this (untested):

```
# calculate magnitude across all entries in list t
def magnitude(t):
    mag = 0.0
    # scan all the lines in t
    for vector in t:
        # vector is a dictionary each entry contains a count
        mag += math.sqrt(sum(v[w]*v[w] for w in v))
    return mag

## normalizes the vectors of the term_frequency matrix
tf_normalize = []
vmag=magnitude(term_frequency)
# for each entry of the term_frequency, i.e. each line of the traindata
for vector in term_frequency:
    # normline is the normalized line
    normline = {}
    # normalize each entry
    for w in vector:
        normline[w] = vector[w]/vmag
    #append to output
    tf_normalize.append(normline)

print(tf_normalize)
```

Good luck. Over and out.

Comment: I have to apologize for the stupid mistake which I made. I edited my post. Actually my question means different now. I meant sth different other than your answer.

Comment: So you are reading traindata the first time, stemming the words and counting their frequency, then reading it again, not stemming this time, and for each line you are counting the unstemmed word occurrences, with an awful lot of zeroes, keeping a full set of these results per line of traindata in term_frequency. Then you are normalizing these frequencies against the overall frequency of the words. Is that correct? Or can you edit your question to better explain a) your question and b) what exactly the error is

Comment: yeah exactly what you said. As you see I made another matrix called tf_normalize in order to save the normalized vectors in it. so it's been two matrices and it's too heavy. The question is how I can save the normalized vectors in the term_frequency (the first matrix was made)

Comment: Hmm. Your normalize function returns in the for loop - so it only looks at the first entry in term_frequency, and always returns that. Is that what you intended? Anyway, continuing with enormous arrays of enormous arrays is probably doomed. Substitute an enormous array of much smaller dictionaries and you are probably less likely to run out of memory.